# returning json with array data

Tags: node.js, api

when I did a console.log({result}) in the nodeJS, I get the response and is the result which is fine.

```
{
  result: {
    likes: [ 5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448 ],
    reviewers: [
      5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448,
      5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448,
      5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448,
      5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448,
      5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448
   
    ],
    _id: 5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448,
    displayname: 'Superman',
    emailacct: 'superman@demo.com',
    date: 2020-11-23T04:20:09.316Z,
    createdAt: 2020-11-23T04:20:09.319Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-12-01T15:03:11.805Z,
  }
}
```

When I try this console.log({user:{id:result._id, name: result.displayname, emailaddress:result.emailacct}}), it also did return the result fine:

```
{
  user: {
    id: 5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448,
    name: 'Superman',
    emailaddress: 'superman@demo.com'
  }
}
```

But when I try this  console.log({user:{likes:likes,reviewers:reviewers,id:result._id, name: result.displayname, emailaddress:result.emailacct}}), it gives an error "DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. What I did was changing the connection string to

```
const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_ATLAS_CONNECTION_STRING,{ 
            useNewUrlParser: true, 
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            **useFindAndModify: false**})
```

It did not show any error anymore but I am not getting anything. It just empty.

How do I return an array of likes and reviewers which is this console.log({user:{likes:likes,reviewers:reviewers,id:result._id, name: result.displayname, emailaddress:result.emailacct}})?

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated? Thanks

Comment: I think you should also read like
`{likes:result.likes, reviewers:result.reviewers}`

Comment: What I am thinking about or where is my mind went to? I should probably take a rest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please accept my answer too. Thanks I need few points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With object spread operator

You should read values like

```
{likes:result.likes, reviewers:result.reviewers}
```